# Hide <li> nested inside two divs

Tags: jquery, hide

I have the following HTML, and want to target hiding the first two `<li>` instances. I am struggling with addressing only the `<li>` inside this list, as I have multiple other lists of the same class on the page, but want to target this one only.

As such, I am looking to be able to nest the jQuery statement targetting the `<li>` inside the `<ul class="ProductList">` inside `<div class="Blockcontent">` inside `<div class="Featured">`

```
<div class="Featured" id="#Featured">
   <div class="BlockContent">
      <ul class="ProductList">
         <li>product here</li>       <--- hide
         <li>product here</li>       <--- hide  
         <li>product here</li>
         <li>product here</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my current attempt:

```
$('.Featured').find('ul:li(2)').hide();
```

How can I modify this to hide only the first two `<li>` elements?

Comment: Couldn't you just give those two list items a unique class name and hide that class?

Comment: Hi guys, the CMS I am suing builds these on the fly so I cannot change the class assignments of the lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery's `slice()` function](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) will allow you to target a specific range of elements for a given selector. For instance to hide the first two `<li>`s in your example, you would want to do:

```
$('#Featured .BlockContent ul.ProductList li').slice(0, 1).hide()
```

Comment: +1 `slice()` is actually faster than the `:lt(n)` selector. (Source: "Additional Notes" in [`:lt()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).)

Answer (score 0):

$('.Featured').find('ul:li(2)').addClass("hide");
/// Where .hide just defines "display: none".

Answer (score 0):

Almost close

```
$('.Featured').find('ul:li(2)').hide();
```

You are supposed be using `eq` to target the elements..

```
$('.Featured ul').find('li:eq(0), li:eq(1)').hide();
```

You can also take the advantage of using `lt`

```
$('.Featured ul').find('li:lt(2)').hide();
```